# Adding a administrate gem gives Zeitwerk error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, zeitwerk, administrate

I am getting a error
`Error: expected file /Users/luqman/Desktop/Checkout/jcom .app/app/dashboards/sessions_dashboard.rb to define constant SessionsDashboard, but didn't`

When I try to run `rails g administrate:install`

My sessions controller is

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Admin::Devise::SessionsController
  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    ActsAsTenant.current_tenant = current_merchant.shop if current_merchant.present?
    super
  end
end
```